# Nested structure to compute area of rectangle given two points (C language)

Tags: c, function, pointers, structure

Function `double computeArea(Rectangle *r)` computes the area of a rectangle using the two point coordinates given, `topLeft` and `botRight`. I'm a little confused as to why my `r` is not passing into the function from the `main` function.

Here's what I did:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <math.h> 

typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
} Point;

typedef struct {
    Point topLeft;   /* top left point of rectangle */
    Point botRight;  /* bottom right point of rectangle */
} Rectangle;

double computeArea(Rectangle *r);

int main()
{
    Point p;
    Rectangle r;

    printf("\nEnter top left point: ");
    scanf("%lf", &r.topLeft.x);
    scanf("%lf", &r.topLeft.y);
    printf("Enter bottom right point: ");
    scanf("%lf", &r.botRight.x);
    scanf("%lf", &r.botRight.y);
    printf("Top left x = %lf  y = %lf\n", r.topLeft.x, r.topLeft.y);
    printf("Bottom right x = %lf  y = %lf\n", r.botRight.x, r.botRight.y);
    printf("Area = %d", computeArea(&r));
    return 0;
}

double computeArea(Rectangle *r)
{
    double height, width, area;

    height = ((r->topLeft.y) - (r->botRight.y));
    width = ((r->topLeft.x) - (r->botRight.x));
    area = height*width;
    return (area);
}
```

Expected output:

```
Enter top left point: 1 1
Enter bottom right point: 2 -1
Top left x = 1.000000  y = 1.000000
Bottom right x = 2.000000  y = -1.000000
Area = 2.000000
```

Output I'm getting instead:

```
Enter top left point: 1 1
Enter bottom right point: 2 -1
Top left x = 1.000000  y = 1.000000
Bottom right x = 2.000000  y = -1.000000
Area = 0
```

Comment: And what's the actual output you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%d` is for printing integers. You can use `%f` to print doubles:

```
printf("Area = %f", computeArea(&r));
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. Forgot about the automatic promotion of float to double rendering the `l` unnecessary (since all floats will be promoted to double anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Two points for you:

1) You're using the wrong format string here:

```
printf("Area = %d", computeArea(&r));
```

`%d` is for integers, `%f` should be used for printing floats. The fact that you're seeing `0` as the returned result is just luck of the draw. Passing a data type that's different than what is expected to `printf` results in undefined behavior, so anything could have happened there.

2) You will be getting the wrong values for area because you're allowing for negative values. You need to take absolute value of `height` and `width` to get the correct area.